# Using Regex : How to exlude a capture in this case?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I'm writing a C# app. I'm trying to build a Regex to match with this kind of expressions (4 examples), to get 6 data on it:

Name Value1 Unity Value2 Value3 Date
**6-Benzyladenine D < 0,01 mg/kg 0,01 5 19/11/2015

3,4-dichloroaniline 0,28 mg/kg 0,01 0,06 20/11/2015

Carbofuran(+3-hydroxy) D < 0,28 mg/kg 0,01 0,5 19/11/2015

Chlorprophame(+3-Chloroanilin 0,28 mg/kg 0,01 5 19/11/2015**

==> according to this pattern :
**example 1**

```
 - Group #1 : Carbendazime(+Benomyl)  
 - Group #2 :   
 - Group #3 : 0,28   
 - Group #4 : mg/kg    
 - Group #5 : 0,01       
 - Group #6 : 5  
 - Group #7 : 19/11/2015
```

**example 2**

```
- Group #1 : 3,4-dichloroaniline  
 - Group #2 : D < 0,28  
 - Group #3 : 0,28   
 - Group #4 : mg/kg    
 - Group #5 : 0,01  
 - Group #5 : 0,06  
 - Group #7 : 20/11/2015
```

I tried this regex :

```
 (.+(?=D < )|(.+))((D\s<\s)?(\d+,?\d*))\s(mg/kg)\s(\d+,?\d*)\s(\d+,?\d*)\s(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/20\d{1,2})
```

But if this works, I don't find the proper values in the right capturing group.
How could I write the best Regex for it?

Comment: regexr.com is not great for  testing .NET regexps, use [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) or [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester). [HERE IS A DEMO OF YOUR REGEX](http://goo.gl/hAoGfc).

Comment: [`^([^\s]+)\s+((?:D < )?\d+,\d+)\s+([a-z]{2}\/[a-z]{2})\s+(\d+,\d+)\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s+(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})$`](https://regex101.com/r/mS2zS8/1)

Comment: It is too unclear, sorry. You seem to want to match substrings that are not present inside the input string.

Comment: Is regex best tool for this? Might be better off using `Split`?

Comment: I wanted to use regex (and regex.match()) because i'm looking for this string in an array.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer of "stribizhev", which make perfectly what I wanted :
([^\s]+)\s+((?:D < )?\d+,\d+)\s+([a-z]{2}/[a-z]{2})\s+(\d+,\d+)\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s+(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})